# How to control smooth and probably custom scrolling in flutter web with mouse and trackpad both

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-web

Initially, I wanted to have smooth scrolling in flutter web, I tried web_smooth_scroll, which had some level of smoothness but while it was used I was unable to use the trackpad to scroll on my laptop.

Now, am looking for a scrolling solution for flutter web where I can manipulate the scroll through scroll_controller which works with a mouse, trackpad, and touchscreen.

Any advice is helpful.